# Jquery remove() dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a templating system that, in some exceptions, have to remove DOM elements after append them to the DOM.

I usually create a jquery object with the template string I have. Ex.:

```
var template = "<div><div class='itenToRemove'>REMOVE!</div><div>DO NOT REMOVE!</div></div>"

var $elementToAppend = $(template);
```

But sometimes I need to remove some part of the element, like

```
$elementToAppend.remove('.itenToRemove')
```

But it does not work! Why not? Appearently, only already inserted elements on DOM works with the remove method.

I have created a jsFiddle that illustrates my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/raphaeldovale/mz6Lrrbh/1/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove passing a selector to .remove() doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I see. It works like a filter, not a find. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $elementToAppend.find(".itemToRemove").remove();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/mz6Lrrbh/3/

PS : There is misspelled 'itenToRemove' which should be 'itemToRemove'

Comment: I understand that the selector in remove method works as a filter and not as a find method. My bad, thank you!

Comment: No worries. Sorry couldn't include the details of the answer in time but guess you figured it out yourself :)