# jQuery remove dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852481/jquery-remove-dynamically-created-elements) but I'm not sure how to structure the jquery code when I have 2 elements and 1 has an onclick event as below:

```
$('.button1').click(function(event) {
  var el_parent = $(this).parent();
  $('<input id="new_input" type="text" />').appendTo(el_parent);
  $('<a href="#" id="button2">Do Something</a>').on('click', function(event2) {
    // some code
  }).appendTo(el_parent);
});
```

If there was just the input field then I assume the following would work:

```
var el_input = '';

$('.button1').click(function(event) {
  var el_parent = $(this).parent();
  el_input = $('<input id="new_input" type="text" />');
  el_input.appendTo(el_parent);
});
```

Then use the following to remove:

```
el_input.remove();
```

But how do I structure the jquery to include button2?

### UPDATE:

As Robin suggests I can remove elements individually, but in the code below I find it shows nothing because it seems the removal is completed after the append. The page includes several buttons of class 'button1' each of which might add an instance of 'new_input' and 'button2', so I want to remove any of these instances before adding new ones with the same id, is that possible or does it conflict with the DOM?

```
$('.button1').click(function(event) {
    $('#new_input').remove();
    $('#button2').remove();      
  var el_parent = $(this).parent();
  $('<input id="new_input" type="text" />').appendTo(el_parent);
  $('<a href="#" id="button2">Do Something</a>').on('click', function(event2) {
    // some code
  }).appendTo(el_parent);
});
```

### UPDATE 2: - change of plan

Decided to not remove elements but instead replace the dynamic input id with a class and fetch the input value using an input name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by '*include button2'* you mean you want to remove that as well, you can select it by its ID:

```
$('#button2').remove();
```

Comment: I could reference the input and anchor button separately like that, I was intending to combine all in one variable, but it's not vital. To combine in one variable I think all I need do is to simply append the input to the variable el_input (rather than el_parent) then append the anchor button to el_input, and then append el_input to el_parent.

Comment: If I put $('#button2').remove(); at the beginning of the click function, to remove any existing instances before dynamically adding a new one, on first click it doesn't show the input and button at all; In Chrome's debug I can see it shows the input and then removes it. Also tried using setTimeout around the code adding the input and button. I hoping to reuse an id for a different parent.